Use QSqlDatabase::driver() to get the issue where the database driver is empty when clion is developing qt
When developing a Qt program in CLion, QSqlDatabase::drivers() shows that the database drivers are empty, but the output of the database drivers in Qt Creator is normal. The Qt version is 6.5.3, the MySQL driver has been compiled, and the MinGW version used is mingw1120_64.
This is the result of clion：

This is the result of qtcreater：

I tried to copy the database driver in Qt to the project folder, but the list is still empty after running.

